# CSS struggling to change text colour for button

Tags: css

You see there is a button on the top right of this homepagepage called quick support - https://www.suretechit.co.uk.

You see the text colour is navy blue to match the other size. I need the button (only) to be white colour text not navy coloured and not affect any of the other parts of the nav bar.

I have tried using the custom class and setting it but am struggling. Example below of what I've tried.

```
#top nav > ul > .button_solid_color_2 > a:before  {
    color: #FFFFFF!important;
}
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<li id="menu-item-6179" class="quick-support menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom button_solid_color_2 menu-item-6179"><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://get.teamviewer.com/suretechsupport">Quick Support</a></li>
                                
                            </ul>
                                                
                    </nav>
```

Is anyone able to help please? It should be a quick fix for any CSS pro's

Comment: hex color codes have 6 digits. `color: #FFFFFF!important;` or 3 if you truncate `#FFF`. your example shows 8 (`color: #FFFFFFFF!important;`), which is too many, otherwise, it should work. Please add the html which corresponds to the css if you need assistance with the selector syntax.

Comment: complete side note, but on the 'about' page, in the second block of text there is a typo (missing 'to' between the words 'important' and 'help' on line 4). Just thought I would let you know.

Comment: @admcfajn I have updated to 6 digits and it still doesn't work. I have added my HTML too!

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to see what to change but it worked by changing following `a` tag.

```css
#top nav >.buttons >li:last-child >a {
        margin-right: 0;
        color: white!important;
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this now, and it is not working